# Syntax Error in Python for Loop while extracting data with beautiful soup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am a Java programmer and new to python language and i know this question is silly. I usually take web scrape data using Jsoup(java) but for a change i wanna give a try with beautiful soup(python) but i ended up with a school boy error. Please help me out.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

for i in  range (0,10,10)
    r=requests.get("http://www.bjp.org/know-your-candidate/?start="+i+"&candidate_state=")
    data=r.text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
    print(soup)
```

**Problem : Syntax Error**

It's showing at the end of the for loop.

Comment: Why are you using a loop here?  `range(0,10,10)` just returns `[0]`, so your loop will only run for 1 iteration.  Perhaps you meant to do `range(10)`, which will return `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`?

Comment: @iCodez Yeah I did that on purpose, just for retrieving one page.Second parameter actually is 400. That's paginated actually it will increment in step of 10 like 0,10,20,... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are indending it properly... All you need is a `:` at the end of the for syntax.

```
for i in  range (0,10,10):
    r=requests.get("http://www.bjp.org/know-your-candidate/?start="+i+"&candidate_state=")
    data=r.text
    soup=BeautifulSoup(data)
    print(soup)
```

`:` colon tells the compiler that the coming line of code is contained in a block.

Answer (score 1):

To this line:

```
for i in  range (0,10,10)
```

Add a `:`:

```
for i in  range (0,10,10):
```

Comment: @RickyDemer: Ah I gotcha. Well it's easy enough to link an account and get 101 rep and leave a comment there. These comments don't really belong on this site so I'm gonna get the rest of them removed too. Thanks for the heads up btw but I think Python 2 is implied if the version isn't specified, doesn't matter much either way.